# Why does iOS not inform my application about audio session interruptions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudiosession

*I am using AVPlayer to play sound from different sources (including iPod music library). Due to the fact that AVPlayer is more low level AVAudioPlayer I have to handle interruptions myself. Using AVAudioPlayer is not an option!*

In the Apple developer documents they mention to either listen `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification`or setup a listener with `AudioSessionInitialize`. But when doing so I **only receive notifications when the interruption ended**, but due to [their documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW7) my app **should be able to handle both**.

I am using the following code to initialize my audio session: (simplified version, removed unimportant lines)

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, ARInterruptionListenerCallback, nil);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

And here is how the listener looks like:

```
void ARInterruptionListenerCallback(void *inUserData, UInt32 interruptionState) {
    if (interruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {
        // Here is the code which is never called...
    }
    else if (interruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {
        // But this case will be executed!
    }
}
```

Btw. I am expecting this code executed when there is an interruption like a phone call or similar. Am I misunderstand what Apple declares as interruption?

Comment: Hey,@miho i also have same issue . when i getting call & siri interruption is working fine began & end both . but when i am opening iPod music library & play some music file then interruption began is called but interruption end is never called why . please any one have a solution for that. please post on SO i will definitely give a upWot .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in iOS 6. The interrupt code never seems to be called for begin interrupt - That includes both the old deprecated method (using AVAudioSession delegate) and the new notification method.

Myself and a few others have raised a high severity bug request with Apple so I suggest you do the same ([bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)) to get their attention.

I'm not sure what you're using the interrupt for, but I was using it to allow audio to resume after the interrupt if necessary, and also update the play/pause button in the interface. I had to change my method to watch the AVPlayer rate property to toggle the play/pause button, and not allow audio to resume after an interruption.

**Edit:** see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676836/avaudiosessiondelegate-called-at-endinterruption-but-begininterruption-not-call/12736557#12736557)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also created a work around like that. I am going to report this issue to now.