# AVAudioSessionDelegate beginInterruption is not called iOS 6.0.1

Tags: ios6, avplayer, interruption, avaudiosessiondelegate

I am creating an iPhone application with music player. I used `AVPlayer` for creating music player. The issue is `beginInterruption` method is not called in iOS 6.0.1 when a phone call arrives. But `endInterruptionWithFlags:flags` called. In lesser versions of iOS it is working fine. And one more thing I noticed is, if a phone call come when the app is in background, `beginInterruption` method is called!! But not when the app is active.

When I searched, I found the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676836/avaudiosessiondelegate-called-at-endinterruption-but-begininterruption-not-call) is noted by some other also, and they stated as it is the bug with apple. And the issue is fixed in iOS 6.1.

So, what should I do? Should I try to fix the issue manually or tell the users to update the OS? At the same time, why it is working when the app is background? Any idea? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think iOS 6.1 fixed it, sigh.

Comment: @olajuwon Did you try it on 6.1? In the link that I mentioned, they said, it is fixed.

Comment: I knew, tried and still not fixed..

Comment: Ok. So how did you manage it in your app?

Comment: My app is at stages of development, if Apple won't fix it when I have to submit to AppStore, I will use a flag to determine is my AVAudioSession suspended cuz I force paused, remote media buffering, route changed. If not any of these things happened, it will be definitely interruption. But this will make code looks dirty, do you have any suggest?

Comment: As of now, i haven't done anything to fix the issue. We submitted the app and approved. We too thinking about use a flag as you said. If Apple fixes the issue, it would be more better. Anyway we will upload the updated version of app with fix.