# Resuming Interrupted Radio Stream using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, internet-radio

I am developing an online radio app for iOS6 devices. Ive looked for various wrappers to achieve this task. AVPlayer, MPMoviePlayerController etc.

I tried using AVPlayer as it sounds more correct to use it for my purpose as it is audio only application. But soon I came across this problem : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676836/avaudiosessiondelegate-called-at-endinterruption-but-begininterruption-not-call/12736557#12736557)

Therefore I switched to MPMoviePlayerController and this is what Im trying to do :

```
    pPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://launch.fusionradio.fm:8004"]];
    pPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    pPlayer.view.hidden = YES;

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    [pPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [pPlayer play];

    pPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(StreamStateChanged) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:pPlayer];
```

In my StreamStateChanged method Im doing :

```
NSLog(@"Trying to replay");
[pPlayer pause];

[pPlayer play];
```

pPlayer is MPMoviePlayer. Everything is fine except when there is an interrupt Console spits out the following :

```
    Took background task assertion (1) for playback stall.
    Ending background task assertion (1) for playback stall.
```

The number after assertion keeps increasing. and then it recovers from it once the internet connection is stable.

My question is : Is this approach correct? Am I doing something wrong along the way? And Is it ok to ignore that assert message?.

P.S : Please suggest if there is a better approach for developing radio streaming app using different API as opposed to MPMoviePlayerController

Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

You are entirely correct in ignoring those internal assert messages. There is nothing you can do about them.

Comment: Thank you Till. I was also confused about these logging messages (`...Took background task assertion (n) for playback stall`) in a big fat video playing app you might have heard of...

Comment: the streaming in my app stops a lot because of this assertion!!, what can i do?

Comment: @Mutawe you are getting it the wrong way around. That assertion is happening a lot because your streaming runs out of content - check the network connectivity and the stream encoding.

Comment: @Till is there any event callback about these messages ?